# ExtJS 4 logout from ExtJS after session is over

Tags: php, extjs

I use CodeIgniter for my backend and ExtJS 4.1 for the frontend. In a controller in CI I check if an users session is over and if so I perform

> redirect('login');

However what actually happen is - I stop to get response from the server but my ExtJS is still working and I don't get the loginpage. How can I redirect from ExtJS when I see on the server side that session is over?

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 2):

```
var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner();

// poll some page every 10 seconds
var task = runner.start({
    run: function() {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'is_logged_out.php',

            success: function(response){
                var json = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

                // is we are logged out then redirect somewhere
                if (json.isLoggedOut) {
                    task.destroy();
                    location.href = json.redirectToPage;
                }
            }
        })
    },
    interval: 10000
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can add special logic to handle 403 errors (presumably if your ExtJs session has expire on the backend, but client still have page opened - next request should get back `Not Authorized` message).

Check out singleton class `Ext.Ajax` for how to subscribe to global Ajax events.

Comment: Hi, Sha. Yeah, the problem is specificly when the user has an open page in ExtJS but for some reason his session has timed-out. If that happens the user is still able to navigate through the page and when a call to the server is made the user doesn't get the info (he's timed out) but also the redirect works only in firebug by which I mean that the login page is loaded in the HTML response but not in the browser, so the user ends up with seeing a blank window. I\m gonna look up through what you mention but i Think there was some issue with the 4xx responses when you use CI for backend.

Answer (score 0):

When an user's session is over, typically is done by the user himself by performing a certain behaviour: for example, the user push the logout button. Well, at that time, the client (ExtJS) should be forward an AJAX request to the server as follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request ({
  url: serverUrl + 'logout' ,
  success: function (response) {
    location.href = serverUrl + 'login';
  } ,
  failure: function (response) {
    // Something here to handle the failure
  }
});
```

When an user logout, that request is reached by the server: your CI app will over the session and response to the client with '200 OK HTTP/1.1' and the client provide to redirect the user to the login page.

Ciao.

Wilk